# Loading QIcons using pkgutil

Tags: python, image, pyqt, pyside

I am attempting to load in images I can't figure out how to load the images using `pkgutil.get_data()` which I would prefer to use since I don't want to have fixed paths in my code.

Currently, I have something like this, which works only when running out of the same folder.

```
...
    self.imagePixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("img/myImage.png")
...
```

The issue then is, if you run the script from other folders the path is messed up and you get this error:

> QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap

I would like to use something like: `pkutil.get_data("img", "myImage.png")` to load the images however this provides the data from the image file where `QPixmap()` wants other kinds of data.

The only "workaround" I can see is to use part of what they specify here: [pkgutil.get_data](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) 
and do something like this:

```
self.myPath = os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__)
self.imagePixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(self.myPath,"img/myImage.png"))
```

This just seems to much of a [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up finding out. I should have rtfm a little closer. Anyway, you can use the `loadFromData()` method to get data from a `QByteArray` and pass it the *format* of the data therein.

```
self.imagePixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
self.imagePixmap.loadFromData(get_data(__name__, "img/myImage.png"), 'png')
```

Here is a link to the information [from here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1):

> `bool QPixmap::loadFromData(const QByteArray &data, const char *format = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)`
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Loads a pixmap from the binary *data* using the specified *format* and conversion *flags*.